# How to split a string on non-alphabetic characters. Regex JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sentence that I want to split into an array of words, but if there is punctuation included I end up with quotes in my array somehow.

```js
console.log("This is an example sentence! Dangit".split(/[\W/]/));

// Outputs: ["This", "is", "an", "example", "sentence", "", "Dangit"]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What about numbers? Do you want to split on numbers or not? FYI: `/` is already included in `\W`

Answer (score 2):

You could take `match` instead and look for word characters.

```js
console.log("This is an example sentence! Dangit".match(/\w+/g))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `[\W]+` instead, which will combine multiple non-word chars together -

```
"This is an example sentence! Dangit".split(/[\W/]+/)

Array(6) [ "This", "is", "an", "example", "sentence", "Dangit" ]
```

Comment: Noting that in this solution, numbers are words too (and hyphenated words become multiple words). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Target spaces and punctuation in single and multiple quantities:

```
[\s.?!,]+
```

```js
console.log("This is an example sentence! Dangit".split(/[\s.?!,]+/));
```